# Checking if ancestor attribute value is a certain value

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a simple kind of layout like the following:

```
<SubSection filter="filter14, filter13, filter12">

   <SubSection>
     <para> test </para>
   </SubSection>

    <SubSection filter="filter1">
      <Reviewer>John Smith</Reviewer>
    </SubSection>
</SubSection>
```

I am using part of the DocBook profile xsl to pull out, in this case, SubSection elements that have filter='filter14', however, i also want to pull out any elements that have filter='filter1' if they are an ancestor of an element having a filter='filter14' value.

I am using the following test, which works excepts for the test for 'filter1' value:

```
<!-- Copy all non-element nodes -->
 <xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()" node="profile">
  <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

 <!-- Profile elements based on input parameters -->
 <xsl:template match="*" mode="profile">

<!-- This is my input for a filter attribute RU -->
<xsl:variable name="filter.content">

<xsl:if test="@filter">
  <xsl:call-template name="cross.compare">
      <!-- <xsl:with-param name="a" select="$profile.filter"/> -->
    <xsl:with-param name="a" select="'filter14'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="b" select="@filter"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="filter.ok" select="not(@filter) or 
   $filter.content != '' or @filter = '' or (@filter = 'filter1' and contains(ancestor::SubSection[@filter], 'filter14'))"/>

<xsl:if  test="$filter.ok">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="profile" select="@*"/>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="profile"/>
    </xsl:copy>

</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

And cross.compare is:

```
 <!-- Returns non-empty string if list in $b contains one ore more values from list $a -->
 <xsl:template name="cross.compare">
 <xsl:param name="a"/>
 <xsl:param name="b"/>
 <xsl:param name="sep" select="$profile.separator"/>

 <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($b, $a)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($b, $a)"/>
 <xsl:if test="contains($b, $a)">1</xsl:if>

 </xsl:template>
```

It seems that this is just finding the right xpath for checking to see if the current element filter attribute = 'filter1' and the  ancestor SubSection element filter attribute contains 'filter14'. I would think this would work, but it isn't.

I am still getting everything with a 'filter14' filter attribute value, as well and any elements not having a filter attribute or a filter attribute value of '', but not one with a filter attribute value of 'filter1'.

Can anyone suggest what is happening here?

Thanks,

Russ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is where you've gone wrong:

```
contains(ancestor::SubSection[@filter], 'filter14')
```

This says "find the first `SubSection` ancestor that has a `@filter` attribute and produce `true` if it contains 'filter14'`.

What you need instead is this:

```
ancestor::SubSection[contains(@filter, 'filter14')]
```

Slightly more robust version:

```
ancestor::SubSection[contains(concat('|', normalize-string(@filter), '|'), '|filter14|')]
```

Comment: Thank you i stumbled across the following:

Comment: @RussUrquhart What did you stumble across?

Comment: Sorry. i thought my code made the paste:

(@filter = 'filter1' and contains(ancestor::SubSection[1]/@filter, 'filter14')

Comment: @RussUrquhart Yes, that will work if you only want to check the nearest `SubSection` ancestor. My approaches above will check all of the `SubSection` ancestors if there are more than one.